# Android bluetoothadapter not emitting ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-device-discovery

I have a class with a broadcast receiver setup. The receiver listens for the following actions:

```
ACTION_FOUND
ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED
ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
```

The found and started actions get emitted as expected, however, the documentation for the BluetoothAdapter specifies that a discovery scan should take ~12 seconds and is then followed by a `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED`. This does not seem to be the case, since I can only manually trigger an emit of the finished action by making a call to `cancelDiscovery()`. If I leave it running long enough, sometimes the event is emitted (but this can take upwards of 1-2 minutes). Sometimes, that doesn't even happen. If I proceed to force the scan to end, by disabling Bluetooth, the action is emitted as expected.

Is the scan supposed to take this long, and am I supposed to manually control the scanning process, i.e. ending it myself after a 12 second countdown? Or am I missing something in the docs. The broadcastreceiver is configured correctly, as evidenced by the arrival of all the actions.

Comment: This behavior is not how it usually behaves. Unfortunately there is a lot of variation, especially on older devices. What handset and android version?

Comment: Nexus 5, 5.1.1 (Lollipop). I also have an Xperia Z3, which seems to be able to start and stop a scan, but doesn't find any devices while scanning (6.0.1 Marshmallow)

Comment: I'm sorry to say, I think you will have to put workarounds in for each version of Android and manufacturers variations. Sadly, This has become pretty normal. You can create your own scan wrapper, which uses a timer to end the scan, and repeat the scan a number of times to last the duration you want. Repeating the scan often finds more devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the Nexus 5 to android version 6.0.1 as well, I seem to be getting a little more consistent results with the `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED`broadcast. It also came to light that my other android phone (Xperia Z3) wasn't finding any devices as per the changes in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.htm , which means that it now also requires the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission, which you need to ask for during runtime. If this is not done, the broadcast will not be received by your application. I hope someone else finds this useful.